# How do I change my Display Name in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I have logged in and confirmed my account by email, but my display name is **user17252202** rather than my name.

How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer. I had to go to my profile (accessible by the first icon after the search bar at the top of the page) and change it there.

It appears this does not affect all users. It could be that if you do not have a public Stack Overflow profile it generates a display name for you.

Comment: It already generates a display name for you, it's _user17252202_.